# Total distance between series of locations in PHP

Tags: laravel, reduce

I'm already using the Haversine Formula, to calculate the distance between two points.

What I want to do now, is sum the distance between a series of locations.

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4
```

I've been able to call the function like so

```
$travelled = 0;
foreach ($this->book->locations as $key => $location) {
    $travelled += Book::getDistance($location, $this->book->locations[$key + 1]);
}
```

But obviously I run into issues, when I'm on the last location, that `$locations[$key + 1]` is an invalid index. I suspect the correct approach is to `reduce` the `locations` using a function that `carrys` the distance into the next execution, but I don't know how to pass in the "next" item to the reduce function, something like....

```
$this->locations->reduce(function ($sum, $location) use ($nextLocation) {
    return $sum + Book::getDistance($location, $nextLocation);
}, 0);
```

Comment: Would (($key + 1) % $this->book->locations->count()) be appropriate? Probably dont want to call count every loop, but you get the point I assume.

Comment: $key goes, 0,1,2,3 and ($key+1)%4 goes 1,2,3,0

Comment: OK that makes sense. ! second.

Comment: Think I missed the bracket before.

Comment: Solved your issue :) ?

Comment: Not quite, because last iteration gives distance between start and finish points

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217415/discussion-between-luke-and-kurt-friars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a quick and simple solution but you can just put an if statement in your foreach to stop the index from causing error, like:

```
$travelled = 0;
$numLocations = $this->book->locations->count();

foreach ($this->book->locations as $key => $location) {
    if ($key === $numLocations - 1) {
        break;
    }

    $travelled += Book::getDistance($location, $this->book->locations[$key + 1]);
}
```